# Can KafkaTemplate lose messages in a message-loop?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Imagine we need to send a sequence of the messages to Kafka using `Spring Boot` `KafkaTemplete`.  We use a message loop like this:

```
list.forEach(value -> kafkaTemplate.send(topic, value));
```

Kafka producer is configured with `acks=1` to ensure every message is received by the broker (let it be for the sake of simplicity that there is only one broker).

Imagine that on the middle of the loop, starting from `n`th message, for some reason the broker start failing to receive messages (stop sending success acknowledgements to the producer). Later, via the `k` iteration over the loop when sending `n+k`th message, the broker gets healthy and is able again to receive messages.

How can `KafkaTemplete` handle such a situation? Will Kafka producer remember that `n` to `n+k-1` messages were not sent successfully and will buffer them in the memory, and somehow will implicitly try to send them before sending `n+k` messages? Or the unsent messages will be lost?

Comment: Refer `retires` property in Kafka Producer config

Comment: Also use the `Future<?>` returned by the template send to test the success/failure (synchronously or asynchronously); right now, you are not checking the result.